# Solving equation involving the ceiling function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, diophantine-equations, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How can I solve the equation $$\lceil \log_{b}{1024} \rceil = n$$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ in terms of $b$? I have seen equations of a similar form ([Solving an equation with floor function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530321/solving-an-equation-with-floor-function) before), but I'm not sure how to proceed with this one.

Comment: You have $n$ and want to find $b$, or what?

Comment: Yeah, I have an positive integer $n$ and wish to find a range of possible values for $b$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**.  An equation involving the ceiling function is not "really" an equation, it is "really" an inequation:
$$\lceil\log_b1024\rceil=n$$
means
$$n-1<\log_b1024\le n\ .$$
If you are familiar with basic properties of logarithms and inequalities, you should not have any trouble completing the solution.

Comment: I obtained $\sqrt[n-1]{1024}>b\geq \sqrt[n]{1024}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good to me!